# How to pass IntPtr from C# to C++

Tags: uwp

We are integrating third party SDK in our UWP C# application. Vendor have provided C++ wrapper where they have provided Camera structure as below.

```
 C++ Wrapper code in header file.
 ======================================

 public ref struct CameraCanvas sealed
  {
    property IntPtr view;

    public:
      CameraCanvas()
        {
        view = nullptr;
        }
  };
```

I keep the Canvas/Image UWP control on mainpage.xaml and want to pass it to C++ wrapper.
Now when I use that wrapper in my C# UWP project then it throw error as below.

[image]

How can I get IntPtr value for this in UWP C# project and how should I pass it on C++ wrapper?

Comment: It isn't clear at all what "this" might be.  Passing raw pointers across language boundaries is very troublesome.  Not the pointer itself, but what it points to matters a lot.  That pointed-to value may have to be converted from one runtime representation to another.  We can't tell what that might be, UWP is reminding you that it can't tell either.  Guessing at this can easily send you into a rabbit hole, but look at IBufferByteAccess as an alternative.

Comment: Is anyone know how to implement IMemoryBufferByteAccess in UWP to get local camera result?